# React Router: SearchParams separated by comma

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this state:

```
{
 marca: 'AUDI',
 modello: 'A4',
 categoria: ['Aziendale', 'Nuovo']
}
```

This is the parameter for the setSearchParams function of react-router

This is the response:

> ?categoria=Aziendale&categoria=Nuovo&marca=AUDI&modello=A4

But I want this:

> ?categoria=Aziendale,Nuovo&marca=AUDI&modello=A4

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not recommended to use commas in a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to serialize the array in some way if you want to send it in the URL queryString. Be sure to use a format that you can easily de-searialize. Note that the comma character `","` will likely be URLencoded.

Here's an example using `JSON` to stringify and parse the `categoria` param, i.e. `"/?marca=AUDI&modello=A4&categoria=%5B%22Aziendale%22%2C%22Nuovo%22%5D"`.

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

const updateParams = () => {
  const params = {
    marca: "AUDI",
    modello: "A4",
    categoria: JSON.stringify(["Aziendale", "Nuovo"])
  };

  setSearchParams(params);
};

...

JSON.parse(searchParams.get("categoria"))?.join(", ")
```

[image: Edit react-router-searchparams-separated-by-comma]

Comment: How can I avoiding url encoding?

Comment: @AttilioIurlaro You probably don't want to ***not*** URL encode, it is done for a reason. `setSearchParams` appears to do this by default. If you don't want to URLEncode the URL path + queryString, you might try manually computing the entire URL string and use the `navigate` function. Again, using commas in the URL isn't suggested.