# How to pass object using useNavigate in React router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const brc = {
 liq : [
{"index":"adc", "fdhsjbs": "12bhsdb"},
{"index":"adc", "fdhsjbs": "12bhsdb"},
{"index":"adc", "fdhsjbs": "12bhsdb"}
] 
};

  const goToPosts = () =>
    navigate({
      pathname: '/posts',
      search: `?${createSearchParams(brc)}`,
    });

  return (
    <div>
      Users
      <button onClick={goToPosts}>Go to Posts</button>
    </div>
  );
```

While using createSearchParams and passing the properties I am getting an error

Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type  URLSearchParamsInit.

Is there any other possible way when a user clicks on the button pass the `brc` object to another component based on route setup

Comment: Your `brc` const doesn't seem syntactically correct. It has `=` instead of `:` for `liq`.

Comment: Other than the typo/syntax issue, does this help answer your question regarding the queryString? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543969/react-router-searchparams-separated-by-comma/72553250#72553250 Or if you just need to pass data from one route to another? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701050/how-to-pass-data-from-a-page-to-another-page-using-react-router/59701168#59701168